# How to remove a substring from a string without using replace() method?

Tags: java

```
String string = "yesnoyesnoyesnoyesno";
String substring = "no";
```

How do I remove every occurrence of the substring from the string so it ends up being "yesyesyesyes"?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 8+, then you could try splitting the input on `"no"` and then joining the resulting array together into a string:

```
String string = "yesnoyesnoyesnoyesno";
string = String.join("", string.split("no"));
System.out.println(string);
```

This prints:

```
yesyesyesyes
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use the `replace()`, so *technically* it meets the brief:

```
String str = string.replaceAll("no", "");
```

Comment: Oh come on... it's legit!

Comment: Actually, AFAIK `replace` uses `replaceAll` under the hood.

Comment: @Tim no. it uses Matcher's replaceAll(), which in turn uses StringBuilder's appendReplacement(), which doesn't even work with strings, but chars.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "yesnoyesnoyesno";   
    String output="";
    for(String token : input.split("no") )
        output = output.concat(token);      
    System.out.println(output);
```

It prints:

```
yesyesyesyes
```